# External login options for Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

We have a Sharepoint Project Management site up and is active amongst our clients. The site url looks like this:

https://projects.acme.com/clients/[client_name]

Each of our clients has to remember (or bookmark) this long url; the users of this site are not very savvy. They fumble with it all the time. We also do not want clients to know who each other are; so client 1 shouldn't know that client 2 is a client.

We would like to put a login form on our website, prompting for user id and password. Then we would like to be able to route the user based on a successful authentication, to the specific web that is theirs.

Is there a good clean way to make this happen? Is forms authentication the way to go? Are there drawbacks to using forms authentication?

Given my url structure, would this approach work?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975136(v=office.12).aspx

Update: I'm not particularly interested in a solution that requires two weeks of effort on the part of a programmer/admin to setup, nor am I particularly interested in one of the commercial solutions that are $4k-8k. I was hoping to discover a pretty straightforward way to get this done in under a day of effort.

Comment: I have just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement it using FBA.

However, if you use only the user ID and the password, the user IDs across all websites will need to be unique (i.e. if client 1 creates a `john.smith` user ID, client 2 will have to use `john-smith` or `johnsmith` or something completely different). The easy solution is to ask additionally for the company name on the login form, the user ID and the password, but then you'll probably have to handle different ways the users will enter the company name (i.e. `acme`, `ACME`, `Acme`, `Acme Ltd`, `Acme Inc`, `Acme Inc.`).

**Update:**

You can also consider [host-named site collections](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288637.aspx) and have URLs like *https://**client_name**.acme.com*. The downside is that [you cannot use Central Administration to create a host-named site collection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288637.aspx#section3) - you can do it by using PowerShell or custom code.

Generally it is highly unlikely you will find a free solution to get your task done in under a day of effort - admittedly, SharePoint does support FBA, but does **not** provide basic things like a login form, a change password form or user management; you need to create them yourself or use some existing solution (e.g. [SharePoint 2010 FBA Pack](http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/)).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to separate users and also make URL's more sweet you have a two ways.

1. Create a web applications per user.
2. Create one application with multi tenancy support. Check more on this [Spence's Harbar article](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010mt1.aspx).

Second approach is more flexible, but harder to implement, and if you plan to have many clients (more than 50) it's the only way.

Comment: I was looking for a straightforward, and relatively fast/cheap way to accomplish this. Sounds like from scanning the article you linked to above that this is a Very Big Deal, and would require a lot of time and effort. I have seen a couple of commercial solutions, but even those end up costing several thousand $$$.

Comment: Ok. All you need is one web app and a series of site collections for your clients. All your clients will be able to authenticate in web app through FBA and you can separate them by managing their  permissions in way that client can interact only with own site.
Also you can have a top level site collection where users can be arrived in case if they forgot their URL. You can also implement in many ways custom solution for redirecting user to their site after authenticating under top level site. This may be achieved with programmed (c#, vb) or even almost without programmed (javascript) solution.